# Getting unwanted characters like "_x000D_" or "x000D" in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for reading and storing data from Excel, but whenever I read a row from the Excel file to insert into the database, `_x000D_` or `x000D` is appended to the title column.

Example: when inserting, the title is 'Demo', and after reading back from the DB, it was converted to 'Demo_X00D_' or 'Demo X00D'.

Comment: That simply a 'return' character at the end of the line, in hexadecimal. convert it back and `trim()`. Your question is lacking a good example.

Comment: It might be useful to see what you have **before** you put it in the database. It might be exactly the same, but perhaps not? I don't like the fact that there seem to be two variants.

Comment: Though I am late but want to share my experience - In such case you can copy the excel cell value in NotePad++ and also type the same text manually. Then check for ASCII conversion (maybe online) for both the texts, you should be able to find the special characters.

Answer (score 6):

Came across this today and I am using this to convert those escape sequences to html entities:

```
preg_replace('/_x([0-9a-fA-F]{4})_/', '&#x$1;', $string);
```

Which changes `_x000D_` into `&#x000D;`

You can take this a step further to render the actual character (which in this case is a carriage return)

```
html_entity_decode(preg_replace('/_x([0-9a-fA-F]{4})_/', '&#x$1;', $string));
```