# Strange word "x000D" in excel after save change by EpPlus

Tags: c#, openxml, epplus

I'm using EpPlus to populate value to a excel template. Everything is ok but the output file have strange word "x000D" as below, could anyone give me some advices?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting unwanted characters like "\_x000D\_" or "x000D" in PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296136/getting-unwanted-characters-like-x000d-or-x000d-in-phpexcel)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about EpPlus in .Net Core project

Comment: Looks like the lines end with a carriage return (0x000D) and a line feed (0x000A) but the parser is only using line feeds as the end of line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have "resolved" this issue by using ClosedXml instead. It works like a charm.